# Mapping Exception nHibernate NPA with EmbeddedId and OneToMany

Tags: c#, jpa, nhibernate

*I've tagged this with JPA because the API should be the same between JPA and NPA, i.e. the setup should be the same. Just replace [] with @ in your mind :)*

I have a OneToMany relationship in my database that I'm trying to map to some Entity classes. The "many" side has a composite PK which is giving me issues. I think I'm doing everything correctly, but I'm getting an exception when initializing the session. I'm using a .NET port of JPA to get attribute-based mapping.

> Could not determine type for:
>   Mariner.Entities.MinimumOrderAmounts.Zone,
>   Mariner.Data, for columns:
>   NHibernate.Mapping.Column(Zone)

Here is the relevant code.

```
[Entity]
[Table(Catalog = "Atom", Schema = "mariner", Name = "MinimumOrderAmountZone")]
public class Zone  {

    [Id]
    [GeneratedValue(Strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)]
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }

    [Length(500, Min = 1)]
    [NotNull]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [Length(4000)]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(MappedBy = nameof(ZoneItem.Zone), Cascade = new[] { CascadeType.ALL })]
    public virtual ISet<ZoneItem> ZoneItems { get; protected set; }

    [OneToMany(MappedBy = nameof(ZoneSchedule.Zone), Cascade = new[] { CascadeType.ALL })]
    public virtual ISet<ZoneSchedule> ZoneSchedules { get; protected set; }        

}

[Entity]
[Table(Catalog = "Atom", Schema = "mariner", Name = "MinimumOrderAmountZoneItem")]
public class ZoneItem {

    [EmbeddedId]
    public virtual ZoneItemId Id { get; set; } 

    [MapsId("Zone")]
    [ManyToOne]
    [JoinColumn(Name = "ZoneId")]
    public virtual Zone Zone { get; set; }

}

[Serializable]
[Embeddable]
public class ZoneItemId {

    [Column(Name ="ZoneId")]
    public virtual Zone Zone { get; set; } 

    public virtual string ItemId { get; set; }

    [Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)]
    [Column(Name ="ItemTypeId")]
    public virtual ItemType ItemType { get; set; }

}
```

Here are the relevant Nuget packages:

```
<package id="NHibernate" version="4.0.4.4000" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="NHibernate.Validator" version="2.0.0.4002" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="NPersistence" version="2.1.0.11" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Help!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just adding a surrogate key column and mapping it instead. It appears that this isn't supported by NPA (which isn't surprising, given it hasn't been updated in 3 years...maybe it's time to move on to something else.